# AWS Organizations SSO PowerUser Can't access or Generate Access Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, single-sign-on

I'm fairly new to AWS Organizations and SSO and I seem to be missing something when it comes to setting up a user.

I've set-up AWS Organizations and SSO OK, and created some OUs and created AWS Accounts within them. I have also sucessfully used SSO to create a new User and assigned them to the PowerUsers Group. The user `power-group-user` can login fine, and create cloud resources such as EC2s.

But what they can't do is find or create programmatic access keys (AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY). Which seems to be a glaring omission from their capabilities.

Have I missed a step in the user set-up, or am I supposed to explicitly grant them permissions for this? It just seems odd that a PowerUser can't generate access keys.

---

**UPDATE** to my original question. I have tracked down the missing keys, of sorts. This [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/aws-single-sign-on-now-enables-command-line-interface-access-for-aws-accounts-using-corporate-credentials/) describes how when you logon via the SSO Console, you get two options for each account: 1) `Console Access` or 2) `Command line or programmatic access`. If you choose the latter then you are able to obtain temporary access keys (by default good for 1 hour) directly from the console.

So I guess my question has now changed to: **is this how it works with SSO?** That is **temporary credentials only?** I'm guessing that is the case, because I think with SSO I'm assuming Roles, and therefore all credentials will be temporary.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the "Power users" managed policy, that does not give access to IAM which is where you'd create access keys, etc..

Power user description:
Provides full access to AWS services and resources, but does not allow management of Users and groups.

Comment: Jack, thanks for the answer. You are correct, but I've also updated my original question, as I think things are a bit more complicated with SSO.

Comment: SSO is temporary credentials yes. And it does not include a sliding expiration either - you get an absolute expiration which is annoying. By default I think it's one hour. If you need to create access keys for things like a service IAM account, you would need to to it with an Admin user not a PowerUser (you can have SSO users with admin rights)